# How to Organize Training Data for AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, training-data

I am training a model and the training data uses images for both the source and the label.

For example, `image1.jpg => label_image.jpg`

The images and their corresponding "label" are in different directories.

So I have images stored like `s3://bucket/v1/imgs` and their labels stored like `s3://bucket/v1/lbls`.

### Question

How do I go about passing this data into an estimator in sagemaker?

I've seen numerous examples, none of which have the data stored in a similar fashion. I've also tried to find the way that sagemaker expects the data to be organized but haven't had much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you should deliver the input in a way that Sagemaker interfaces expect. However if you want it to be flexible you may want to look at this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-your-own-processing-container.html

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker is mostly agnostic to how you structure your data. As you have:

```
s3://bucket/v1/imgs
s3://bucket/v1/lbls
```

Pass:

```
estimator.fit({'channel_name': 's3://bucket/v1'})
```

And you'll see these two directories on the training instance:

```
/opt/ml/input/data/channel_name/imgs
/opt/ml/input/data/channel_name/lbls
```

Your script should load them as you normally do in a local environment.